# Html doesn't fill entire available space

Tags: html, css, height, width

My "html" div (I don't know what else to call it) doesn't fill the entire page. It extends as far as it can horizontally, but not vertically. If I inspect the "html" div and then scroll down far enough, there's about 1000 pixels of space which is outside of the "html" div. What's strange is that there are other divs in this space...I don't understand how they can exist where there is no html.

The reason this is a problem is that I'm trying to fix a footer to the bottom of the page, but it's just fixing to the bottom of my html, and therefore it isn't placed all the way at the bottom, so it cuts across some other divs.

**To be clear, by 'page', I mean the *entire page*. Not just the visible portion I can currently see in my browser window, but literally every pixel that is *possible* to see by scrolling vertically or horizontally. So changing the footer's position to fixed is not a solution.**

**custom.css:**

```
@import "bootstrap";

html {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!--...--></head>
<body
  <!--...-->
  <div id="footer"></div>
  <div class="container"><%= yield %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I set html's `height: 100%`, it apparently just fills the visible screen, so it becomes even smaller.

Strangely, the entire page is turned blue by making body's `background: blue`, even though the body doesn't extend over the entire page. Stranger still, when I remove body's `background` attribute and instead set html's `background: blue`, the extent of the html stays white, but the remaining part of the page that isn't included in html turns blue.

Anyone know how I can make the html fill the entire page?

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem: height fill up, but width stays fixed. I've tried every variation of width/height 100% there is. Hope you find a solution for us both!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Try changing the order of your elements (container and footer) and using the following CSS ([CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EawKZW)).

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">Something in my container</div>
        <div id="footer">Something in my footer</div>
    </body>
</html>

body {
  background: blue;
}

.container {
  height: 980px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#footer {
  clear: left;
  height: 60px;
  background: green;
}
```

Try setting your footer to a fixed position, and bottom to 0px. You don't need to muck about with html or body here from what I understand in you question.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I want the footer at the bottom of the _page_, not the _screen_. But the bigger issue is that html isn't taking up all the space that it should be.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the HTML element does here. It's the parent element on the page, which means it fills the page natively. Your footer and container elements are child elements; they too will fill the full window natively or as specified with width/height 100%/auto. To position the footer to the bottom of the page, you could move your container above the footer, float it, then clear the float in your footer. I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

T think this will solve your problem

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body <!--...-->
  <div id="footer"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want the footer at the bottom of the _page_, not the _visible screen_. So it should only be visible when a user scrolls down as far as he can go.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move the footer to underneath the container? and remove the positioning on the footer.

```
<body>
  <div class="container"><%= yield %></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem when trying to view my website. I needed a  tag in my html in order for the html to be the entire size of the device viewport. I put this line right after the  tag and before the  tag.

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Hope this helps!